# Design Pattern for derived classes also having a derived child property

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm looking for a class structure or design pattern to implement a base class that has a list of "base items", where several derived classes have the same list but that list is of derived "base items".

Here's a vastly stripped down example (ignore the accessibility of properties, they wouldn't actually all have public setters and default constructors):

```
public class BaseTransaction {
    public List<BaseTransactionItem> Items { get; set; }
    public void AddItem(string description, int quantity, decimal price)
    {
        // Add a new BaseTransactionItem to Items
    }
}

public class BaseTransactionItem {
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class OrderTransaction : BaseTransaction {
    public List<OrderTransactionItem> Items { get; set; }
    public int Deposit { get; set; }
    public void SetDeposit(int depositAmount)
    {
        // Do some stuff to set the deposit.
    }
}

public class OrderTransactionItem : BaseTransactionItem
{
    public int QuantityFulfilled { get; set; }
}

public class RetailTransaction : BaseTransaction {
    public List<RetailTransactionItem> Items { get; set; }
    public List<Tender> Tenders { get; set; }
    public void AddTender(Tender tender)
    {
        // Add a tender to the RetailTransaction
    }

    public decimal TotalTax
    {
        get { return Items.Sum(i => i.Tax); }
    }
}

public class RetailTransactionItem : BaseTransactionItem
{
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}
```

The way I need to work with these classes is that you start with a `BaseTransaction` and add some items to it, and then it can become either an `OrderTransaction` or a `RetailTransaction`. These both share most of their logic and properties with a `BaseTransaction` but have specific extra fields and methods, as well as the `List<BaseTransactionItem>` becoming a `List<OrderTransactionItem>` or a `List<RetailTransactionItem>` respectively.

Further more, after a `BaseTransaction` is "promoted" to a `RetailTransaction`, it may be "demoted" back to a `BaseTransaction` and then "promoted" to an `OrderTransaction` (but never from a `RetailTransaction` to an `OrderTransaction` in this case).

I've tried several approaches to this, with generics, the Decorator pattern (which doesn't seem appropriate), TypeConverters, and yet nothing seems to fit. The only possible solution I've thought of that works is having the `RetailTransaction` class have a constructor that takes a `BaseTransaction` and copying over all the properties and converting the list using `.Cast<RetailTransactionItem>` but this will make maintaining the derived classes pretty difficult.

If it wasn't for the list type needing to change this would be a simple case of using inheritance. I'm completely open to alternative approaches such as those favouring composition over inheritance but since the `RetailTransaction` and `OrderTransaction` classes truely are more specific versions of `BaseTransaction`, inheritance seems to fit - at least in my mind.

Comment: When `RetailTransaction` is "demoted" to `BaseTransaction` and then is "promoted" to `OrderTransaction` how is the `QuantityFulfilled` field of `OrderTransactionItem` class supposed to be populated?

Comment: They aren't - once "demoted" the extra properties on OrderTransaction and its child items should be trashed. In the actual use case there's a UI where you decide whether your BaseTransaction becomes an OrderTransaction or a RetailTransaction, but there will need to be a "back" button in case you choose the wrong option. I also need to be able to show a mixed list of OrderTransactions and RetailTransactions and use XAML data templating to display them differently (which requires them to at least have a common base to co-exist in a collection).

Comment: Just realised I kind of didn't answer your question. When a BaseTransaction is "promoted" the fields that only exist on the RetailTransaction or OrderTransaction and their items will initially be at default/null values, at which point those properties will be set via the UI and then the RetailTransaction or OrderTransaction will be persisted to a database. They can then be retrieved later on but at that point they won't be able to be "demoted". The "demotion" purely functions to serve usability during the creation of a transaction in case of the wrong option being chosen.

Comment: _"I've tried several approaches to this...and yet nothing seems to fit"_ -- most likely because what you're trying to do is itself a flawed concept. Generic _interfaces_ would work, as long as you're willing and able to comply with the generic variance rules. Trying to use `List<T>` just won't work, because it simply won't be possible to ensure type-safety at compile time: if the base class could support base-typed list elements, then it could add invalid types of elements to the list of a derived class.

Comment: The question is too broad, but generally speaking: your "promotion"/"demotion" paradigm sounds like you really ought to solve it just by copying all the objects for the purpose. You can use a single generic class, rather than inheritance, for the transaction type, providing the base and derived "item" types as necessary when "promoting" or "demoting".